# parse.com javascript app. How to update other user roles as Admin

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have seen that this can be done using cloud code. 
But I am not sure how to create a function in cloudcode and executing/Invoking it with parameters from Javascript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  To make a user and admin, one must add that user to the admin role's users.  Here's a cloud function to do that...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setUserAdmin", function(request, response) {
    var user;
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    return userQuery.get(request.userId).then(function(result) {
        user = result;
        var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        roleQuery.equalTo("name", "admin");
        // here's our defense against mischief: find the admin role
        // only if the requesting user is an admin
        roleQuery.equalTo("users", request.user);
        return roleQuery.first();
    }).then(function(role) {
        if (!role) {
            return Parse.Promise.error("only admins can add admins");
        }
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        var relation = role.relation("users");
        relation.add(user);
        return role.save();
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Calling that from the JS sdk...

```
var params = { userId: someUserId };
return Parse.Cloud.run("setUserAdmin", params).then(function(result) {
    // handle success
}, function(error) {
    // handle error
});
```

Comment: why should we exclusively prevent masterkey usage? Does parse.com apply this security? Should we do any settings to allow admins to access masterkey?

Comment: userMasterKey is equivalent to saying: give this process root access until response.success or error.  We don't want to grant that to just any cloud caller, since anybody could lift your javascript key and make a cloud call.  Since the code protects itself against non-admin users, we could have called useMasterKey at the top, but parse recommends a good coding practice to make the call later, after your logic explicitly decides to grant extraordinary permission.